# How is concurrency handled when not using Task.Run() to schedule the work?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

If we fill a list of Tasks that need to do both CPU-bound and I/O bound work, by simply passing their method declaration to that list (Not by creating a new task and manually scheduling it by using `Task.Start`), how exactly are these tasks handled?

I know that they are not done in parallel, but concurrently.

Does that mean that a single thread will move along them, and that single thread might not be the same thread in the thread pool, or the same thread that initially started waiting for them all to complete/added them to the list?

**EDIT:** My question is about how exactly these items are handled in the list concurrently - is the calling thread moving through them, or something else is going on?

Code for those that need code:

```
public async Task SomeFancyMethod(int i)
{
    doCPUBoundWork(i);
    await doIOBoundWork(i);
}


//Main thread

List<Task> someFancyTaskList = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
    someFancyTaskList.Add(SomeFancyMethod(i));
// Do various other things here --
// how are the items handled in the meantime?
await Task.WhenAll(someFancyTaskList);
```

Thank you.

Comment: The question is unclear. There's no manual scheduling of tasks. Tasks in fact are essentially `their method declaration`. They aren't threads, they represent something that will complete in the future. That something may be a delegate or an IO task. How they run depends on the task scheduler used to execute them - either they run on a thread from a pool, a thread from an IO thread pool, if they represent async IO operations they may use IO completion ports

Comment: It looks like you're trying to duplicate what tasks already do. You don't need to do that. You don't need to "manually" schedule tasks, in fact, you can't do that at all. When you call `Task.Start` the task will still be submitted to a TaskScheduler for scheduling according to that scheduler's algorithm

Comment: If you use `Task.Run`, you can create a task that will be scheduled to the default scheduler. If you use `Task.Factory.StartNew` you can do a custom scheduler, but you are again scheduling the task.
Manual scheduling implies just that - creating a task that's not yet scheduled. Configuring its options, and starting it "manually" by passing in the Task.Start(<Task Scheduler, if any, else use default>) method.

Comment: If you check the source of Task.Start at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs,104 you'll see it uses the "default" TaskScheduler, so there's no manual scheduling at all

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you're asking, but if you're talking about creating your own `TaskScheduler` class to pass to `Task.Factory.StartNew`, then the [documentation for the `TaskScheduler` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) has quite a lot of reading. Have you looked at that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you misunderstood the point. When you create a task either via `Task.Run`, or via `Task.Factory.StartNew` you are effectively returned a task already scheduled somewhere. If you create a task by declaring one, as by using `Task a = new Task(<action here>)`, you are effectively creating an *unscheduled* task. You have to schedule it, hence there is manual scheduling. It won't do it by itself.

Comment: Even if you create a `Task` with `new Task`, you don't need to "manually schedule" it. You just call `Start()` and it will be scheduled for you. You can [look at the code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,905) if you're wondering how it schedules it.

Comment: @GabrielLuci that's my point. Until you call `Start()`, the task is not scheduled.

Comment: Use less words and more C#. It's still unclear what you are doing.

Comment: There really is little difference between using `Task.Run` and `new Task(...).Start()`. If you look at the code, you will see that both end up calling [`ScheduleAndStart()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,107ac97251bea153).

Comment: Assuming things indeed are what they look like, `SomeFancyMethod` does not return to the caller until `doCPUBoundWork` is fully done. Then it executes the `await` and that returns the execution to `someFancyTaskList.Add(SomeFancyMethod(i))` which may now proceed to the next `i`. The entire list is filled in that manner, and then the started tasks are awoken, one at a time, when their respective events occur, on which they in turn `await`.

Comment: @GSerg could you expand this into a standalone answer, especially in regards to these events, and how they expand?

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob Unless `doIOBoundWork` All this code runs on the original thread. The methods are executed to completion each time `SomeFancyMethod(i)` is called.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos are you sure they are executed each time the Task result is attempted to be added to the list? I believe the first `await` returns control to the loop, effectively adding an incomplete task. I'm not sure how they are resolved though, and when. When we explicitly await them, when using `await Task.WhenAll` for example?

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob only if `doIOBoundWork` does something really asynchronous. Otherwise *it* will run to completion. Right now, all those methods will run synchronously at least up to `doIOBoundWork`. If `doIOBoundWork` doesn't do anything really asynchronous, ie use `Task.Run` or use an async IO method like Stream.ReadAsync, they'll run to completion each time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed. Even if you`await` something that is synchronous, it will just complete as if it were synchronous. I've written pseudo-code - the names imply the meaning. Thank you.

Comment: Write real code then. The specifics matter. What you posted can deadlock. Now, if `doIOBoundWork` is truly async, things get weird - without `ConfigureAwait(false)` *all* continuations will try to resume on the original sync context. In a desktop app, that would be the UI thread. So, all continuations will try to continue on the UI thread. Which is already blocked, hence, deadlock. Same for ASP.NET threads. Console apps have no sync context so they won't deadlock.

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob if `doIOBoundWork` is a fake async, there won't be a deadlock.

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob ASP.NET Core doesn't have a sync context either, so the code won't deadlock there either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you, I'm aware of these concerns. I simply wanted to keep it clean and not divulge in the grand scheme of things. I'd have to supply the environment as well, and I might as well have conjured a real example. The nuances are a lot, but the question would become unclear if I expanded it like that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Why would it deadlock? It's using `await Task.WhenAll`, not `Task.WaitAll`. The main thread is not blocked.

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob what's the question then? There's no thread moving among tasks. All methods have run sequentially until the first real `await` inside `doIOBoundWork`. What happens next depends on the platform

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob in Console and ASP.NET Core apps, *after* a real await, the continuations can run on any thread. In desktop and ASP.NET, all continuations will run on the sync context, one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asynchronous methods always start running synchronously. The magic happens at the first `await`. When the `await` keyword sees an *incomplete* `Task`, it returns its own incomplete `Task`. If it sees a *complete* `Task`, execution continues synchronously.

So at this line:

```
someFancyTaskList.Add(SomeFancyMethod(i));
```

You're calling `SomeFancyMethod(i)`, which will:

1. Run `doCPUBoundWork(i)` synchronously.
2. Run `doIOBoundWork(i)`.
3. If `doIOBoundWork(i)` returns an incomplete `Task`, then the `await` in `SomeFancyMethod` will return its own incomplete `Task`.

Only then will the returned `Task` be added to your list and your loop will continue. So the CPU-bound work is happening sequentially (one after the other).

There is some more reading about this here: [Control flow in async programs (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/control-flow-in-async-programs)

As each I/O operation completes, the continuations of those tasks are scheduled. How those are done depends on the type of application - particularly, if there is a context that it needs to return to (desktop and ASP.NET do unless you specify `ConfigureAwait(false)`, [ASP.NET Core doesn't](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html)). So they might run sequentially on the same thread, or in parallel on ThreadPool threads.

If you want to immediately move the CPU-bound work to another thread to run that in parallel, you can use `Task.Run`:

```
someFancyTaskList.Add(Task.Run(() => SomeFancyMethod(i)));
```

If this is in a desktop application, then this would be wise, since you want to keep CPU-heavy work off of the UI thread. However, then you've lost your context in `SomeFancyMethod`, which may or may not matter to you. In a desktop app, you can always marshall calls back to the UI thread fairly easily.

Comment: Of course, there's also a cost to `Task.Run` - if `SomeFancyMethod` _does_ need the synchronization context, you've just broken your application :D

Comment: @Luaan True! I'll mention that in my answer.

Comment: Thank you Luci, I appreciate all your help in all my previous questions on this site! To see if I understood you correctly -> we populate a list of incomplete tasks in my example, because after every true `await`, control is returned to the caller, which effectively adds the incompleted task to the list.

The tricky concept to realize is when the I/O operation has been done. If the I/O method (or we) didn't use `ConfigureAwait`, the continuation will be picked up by a thread, with an added syncctx that allows us to manipulate our application.

Comment: What exactly happens next? And, what will happen if the other 9 I/O operations completed in that very same instance? What I think: Multiple threads will be fighting to get that syncttx, but the thread before it is using it. In our case, won't that thread simply return a completed task (because after the `await` we have no more code in the method), effectively avoiding a deadlock there? Or am I misunderstanding something major? I'm also curious as to how exactly the thread returns the completed task.

Comment: *"If the I/O method (or we) didn't use ConfigureAwait, the continuation will be picked up by a thread"* - When you say "a thread", it suggests "any thread", which isn't true. It will be picked up in the context it started on. In a desktop app, it's the UI thread. In ASP.NET, it's the context of the request. In ASP.NET Core, there is no context.

Comment: *"Multiple threads will be fighting to get that syncttx"* - They won't be fighting. They (the tasks, not threads) will just be scheduled one after the other as the I/O operations finish. There won't be any deadlock as long as you asynchronously wait, like you already are when you use `await Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: I always thought that beneath it all, the synchronization context that is delegated back and forth is what defines a thread to be the UI thread, or a particular request thread, because it has that initially captured context. Can you recommend me something to read in regards to that knowledge?

In ASP.NET I'm guessing there's a number of dedicated threads to handling requests - wouldn't *any* of them handle the job, or it will be specifically the one that initially started it?

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob Probably https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: This might help: [What Is SynchronizationContext](http://hamidmosalla.com/2018/06/24/what-is-synchronizationcontext/). For UI apps, there is only one UI thread. The "context" will always bring you back to that thread. For ASP.NET, the context can be rebuilt on a different thread (not always, but it can). In ASP.NET Core, there is no context at all.

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob The synchronization context doesn't specify a thread - it says what is supposed to happen when the code is ready to continue. For a Winforms application, that means "post a delegate to the UI thread" (as if you did `Invoke`). For an ASP.NET application, that means things like "restore the HttpContext object". That can be done through thread affinity, just like in Winforms, but it usually isn't necessary - if you can ensure the code is written correctly. ASP.NET was designed to be largely compatible with ASP, and many ASP pages required thread affinity.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't mean passing their method *declaration*, but just invoking the method, like so:

```
var tasks = new Task[] { MethodAsync("foo"), 
                         MethodAsync("bar") };
```

And we'll compare that to using `Task.Run`:

```
var tasks = new Task[] { Task.Run(() => MethodAsync("foo")), 
                         Task.Run(() => MethodAsync("bar")) };
```

First, let's get the quick answer out of the way. The first variant will have lower or equal parallelism to the second variant. Parts of `MethodAsync` will run the caller thread in the first case, but not in the second case. How much this actually affects the parallelism depends entirely on the implementation of `MethodAsync`.

To get a bit deeper, we need to understand how async methods work. We have a method like:

```
async Task MethodAsync(string argument)
{
  DoSomePreparationWork();
  await WaitForIO();
  await DoSomeOtherWork();
}
```

What happens when you call such a method? *There is no magic*. The method is a method like any other, just rewritten as a state machine (similar to how `yield return` works). It will run as any other method until it encounters the first `await`. At that point, it may or may not return a `Task` object. You may or may not await that `Task` object in the caller code. Ideally, your code should not depend on the difference. Just like `yield return`, `await` on a (non-completed!) task returns control to the caller of the method. Essentially, the contract is:

- If you have CPU work to do, use my thread.
- If whatever you do would mean the thread isn't going to use the CPU, return a promise of the result (a `Task` object) to the caller.

It allows you to maximize the ratio of what CPU work each thread is doing. If the asynchronous operation doesn't need the CPU, it will let the caller do something else. It doesn't *inherently* allow for parallelism, but it gives you the tools to do any kind of asynchronous operation, including parallel operations. One of the operations you can do is `Task.Run`, which is just another asynchronous method that returns a task, but which returns to the caller immediately.

So, the difference between:

```
MethodAsync("foo");
MethodAsync("bar");
```

and

```
Task.Run(() => MethodAsync("foo"));
Task.Run(() => MethodAsync("bar"));
```

is that the former will return (and continue to execute the next `MethodAsync`) after it reaches the first `await` *on a non-completed task*, while the latter will *always* return immediately.

You should usually decide based on your actual requirements:

- Do you need to use the CPU efficiently and minimize context switching etc., or do you expect the async method to have negligible CPU work to do? Invoke the method directly.
- Do you want to encourage parallelism or do you expect the async method to do interesting amounts of CPU work? Use `Task.Run`.

Comment: I'm a little confused - what do you mean by "when we use `Task.Run`, it returns *immediately* to the caller"? My understanding is that Task.Run schedules the work for another thread to do. When that thread finishes the work, what exactly happens? It just returns the promise to that work (if any) or a completed task, to whatever thread is awaiting for it. If we write a synchronous lambda as in your example, how does it immediately return, especially when it could take minutes to compute the work?

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob `Task.Run` returns immediately - that doesn't mean the promise is completed. It just means the caller of `Task.Run` can do something else in the meantime. `Task.Run` doesn't execute `MethodAsync` before returning - it schedules `MethodAsync` to be run, and returns immediately. It doesn't wait for the task to get started, it doesn't wait for it to reach the first await, it doesn't wait for it to finish. There's no magic in this - it's just the difference between passing the result of a method call and a delegate.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understood what you meant. If we write it as it is, the thread handling the `Task.Run` call will return immediately, because Task.Run schedules the work to be executed on a thread pool thread. This has more to do with how `Task.Run` functions, rather than the difference between passing the result of a method call and a delegate, correct? When we add await/async to `Task.Run`, it behaves as you'd expect with that knowledge.  Instead of saying what I've already read, here is the material in regards to that topic - https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-task-run-async-await

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob Ignore tasks for a moment, and think about normal methods. If you have `string DoSomething();`, you can either call it (`DoSomething()`), or you can create a delegate to it (`() => DoSomething()`). The first executes `DoSomething`, but the second doesn't. The same way, `DoSomethingAsync()` executes (part of) the method, but `() => DoSomethingAsync()` doesn't. If you did `Task.Run(DoSomethingAsync())` (which isn't allowed for obvious reasons), you lose the delayed execution, regardless of the internal implementation of `Task.Run`.

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob As soon as you `await` the task, you force everything to execute logically synchronously; you don't really care about the distinction between a pure async method and one that does CPU work. It's only when you want to launch multiple tasks in parallel that you really care. `await` is what restores the logical synchronous operation, pretending as if your method was a simple synchronous method.

Comment: @SupportMonica-SpiritBob But that's just talking about the general patterns. Specifically, `Task.Run` behaves the way you say, and it needs to use delegates to allow that to happen. This is what makes `Task.Run` useful - allowing you to decouple your inherently synchronous code from the parts you want to execute (at least for a while) asynchronously with respect to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code rewritten without async/await, with old-school continuations instead. Hopefully it will make it easier to understand what's going on.

```
public Task CompoundMethodAsync(int i)
{
    doCPUBoundWork(i);
    return doIOBoundWorkAsync(i).ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        doMoreCPUBoundWork(i);
    });
}

// Main thread
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Task task = CompoundMethodAsync(i);
    tasks.Add(task);
}
// The doCPUBoundWork has already ran synchronously 10 times at this point

// Do various things while the compound tasks are progressing concurrently

Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    // The doIOBoundWorkAsync/doMoreCPUBoundWork have completed 10 times at this point
    // Do various things after all compound tasks have been completed
});

// No code should exist here. Move everything inside the continuation above.
```

Comment: Written like that, on which threads will the continuation of `doIOBoundWorkAsync` continue? I know that to mimic `await/async` behavior when using `ContinueWith`, one has to do `.ContinueWith(continuationAction,
    SynchronizationContext.Current != null ?
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() :
        TaskScheduler.Current)`

Comment: That's correct. By default the `ContinueWith` will schedule the continuations to `TaskScheduler.Current`, which is normally the `TaskScheduler.Default`, which schedules the continuations to the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: It should also be noted that `await` _doesn't_ use task continuations. It does roughly show what it does _logically_, though.